# Apple Pay button not showing in real device but showing in simultaor

Tags: ios, flutter, stripe-payments, applepay, google-pay

I am using [pay](https://pub.dev/packages/pay) plugin in flutter app i am using default [configjsonfile](https://github.com/google-pay/flutter-plugin/tree/main/pay/example/lib/payment_configurations.dart#L27) for apple pay.
And Also i setup following

1. Add SandBox tester in apple console
2. Login through sandbox tester in device
3. add credit card in wallet app.

Still apple pay button not showing .

Here is Apple Button Code

```
final paymentItems = [
      const PaymentItem(
        label: 'Total',
        amount: '99.99',
        status: PaymentItemStatus.final_price,
      )
    ];



 ApplePayButton(
                      paymentConfiguration:
                          PaymentConfiguration.fromJsonString('''{
  "provider": "apple_pay",
  "data": {
    "merchantIdentifier": "merchant.com.kezo.app",
    "displayName": "Sam's Fish",
    "merchantCapabilities": ["3DS", "debit", "credit"],
    "supportedNetworks": ["amex", "visa", "discover", "masterCard"],
    "countryCode": "US",
    "currencyCode": "USD",
    "requiredBillingContactFields": ["emailAddress", "name", "phoneNumber", "postalAddress"],
    "requiredShippingContactFields": [],
    "shippingMethods": [
    {
      "amount": "0.00",
      "detail": "Available within an hour",
      "identifier": "in_store_pickup",
      "label": "In-Store Pickup"
    },
    {
      "amount": "4.99",
      "detail": "5-8 Business Days",
      "identifier": "flat_rate_shipping_id_2",
      "label": "UPS Ground"
    },
    {
      "amount": "29.99",
      "detail": "1-3 Business Days",
      "identifier": "flat_rate_shipping_id_1",
      "label": "FedEx Priority Mail"
    }
    ]
  }
}'''),
                      paymentItems: paymentItems,
                      style: ApplePayButtonStyle.black,
                      type: ApplePayButtonType.buy,
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0),
                      onPaymentResult: onApplePaymentResult,
                      loadingIndicator: const Center(
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                      ),
                    ),
```

when i run in real device childOnError function executed but my device already have wallet app with card setup.

```
 childOnError: const Text(
                          'Apple Pay is not available in this device'),
```

Comment: Please  share code segment for better understanding of your problem statement

Comment: You probably have not completed the integration requirements for Apple Pay yet. Is that the case?
Make sure to enable Apple Pay in your Xcode project and issue the required certificates and give it another go. Refer this: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/passkit/apple_pay/setting_up_apple_pay

Comment: Did you find anything? I'm facing same issue